# View event value in object in jQuery resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have the following code using the resizable jQuery UI plugin:

```
$this.on("resize", function(event,ui){
    console.log(event.pageX);
    console.log(event);
}
```

The output I get is:

> undefined
> [object Object]

How can I view the X and Y coordinates of the event, and in general, how can we view the contents of an object in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Firebug in Firefox to debug this? If so you can set a breakpoint and inspect the object when it hits the breakpoint.